# Toolbox controls are disabled in visual studio 2010?

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, visual-web-part, tools

When I create an empty SharePoint 2010 project with Visual Studio 2010, a lot of controls are disabled (chart, sqlDatasource). I try to reinitialize and other stuff but nothing. The controls are disabled.

How can I develop a webpart without controls?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the .NET Framework built-in charting is only available starting with .NET 4 - but SharePoint 2010 solutions are based on .NET Framework 3.5 - therefore the SharePoint VS solution properties target framework is set to 3.5 - therefore you cannot select this library.

Only option you have is to download and utilize [MSChart control](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422).

You can also check:

- [Visual Studio 2010 toolbox controls disabled or inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871531/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-controls-disabled-or-inactive)
- [Toolbox items grayed out in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587122/toolbox-items-grayed-out-in-vs-2010)